# WS2 API-M 3.2.0. I can't login to Admin Dashboard when User Store is from WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We have installed API Manager 3.2.0. Our user store is configured as LDAP, where user admin and role admin were created earlier by WSO2 Identity server.
According to WSO2 API Manager 3.2.0 documentation:

- I created a user;
- I created a role with permissions "All Permissions > Admin
  Permissions > Manage > API-M Admin" and  "All Permissions > Admin
  Permissions > Login";
- I assigned this role to user.

But I cant' login to admin dashboard  (https://:9443/admin) . Only message:

> "Error 403 : Forbidden The server could not verify that you are
> authorized to access the requested resource."

appears.
More, I can't  login to admin dashboard as user with admin role.
May be our User store is configured in a wrong way.

```
    [super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "*********"
create_admin_account = false

[user_store]
class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager"
type = "database"

[user_store.properties]
ConnectionURL = "ldaps://ldap1.vu.lt:636"
ConnectionName = "cn=admin,dc=vu,dc=lt"
ConnectionPassword = "Super.Chief.IS.17"
type = "read_write_ldap"
UserSearchBase = "ou=users,dc=vu,dc=lt"
UserNameAttribute= "uid"
UserNameSearchFilter = "(&amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))"
UserNameListFilter = "(objectClass=identityPerson)"
UserEntryObjectClass="identityPerson"
ReadGroups = true
GroupSearchBase = "ou=groups,dc=vu,dc=lt"
GroupNameAttribute = "cn"
GroupNameListFilter = "(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)"
GroupNameSearchFilter = "(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(cn=?))"
GroupEntryObjectClass= "groupOfUniqueNames"
MembershipAttribute = "uniqueMember"
BackLinksEnabled = "true"
SCIMEnabled = "true"
PasswordHashMethod = "PLAIN_TEXT"
MultiAttributeSeparator = ","
MaxUserNameListLength = "100"
MaxRoleNameListLength = "100"
UserRolesCacheEnabled = "true"
ConnectionPoolingEnabled = "false"
LDAPConnectionTimeout = "5000"
ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin="true"
ConnectioRetryDelay="12000"
IsBulkImportSupported="true"
defaultRealmName="WSO2.ORG"
EmptyRolesAllowed="true"
WriteGroups="true"
UsernameJavaRegEx="[a-zA-Z0-9._\\-|//]{3,30}$"
PasswordJavaRegEx="^[\\S]{5,30}$"
RolenameJavaRegEx="[a-zA-Z0-9._\\-|//]{3,30}$"
EnableMaxUserLimitForSCOM="false"
PasswordJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg="Slaptazodis neatitinka uzduotoms taisyklems"
PasswordJavaScriptRegEx="^[\\S]{5,30}$"
UsernameJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg="Naudotojo vardas neatitinka reikalavimams"
UsernameJavaScriptRegEx="^[\\S]{3,30}$"
kdcEnabled="false"
```

Any thoughts? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved. There is missing attribute memberOf in LDAP description. I'am sorry